# Display Einstein Activity Capture component of a related object

Tags: einstein

I have a custom object with a lookup field to an Account record and I would like to display the Einstein Activity Capture data of the Account in my custom object page.

This is the part of my Account I would like to display in my custom object:
[image]

Is it possible to achieve that?

I saw there is an Activities Lightning component but I can't display it for a related object.